# Adding selector on ember-growl-notification flash message

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using ember growl notification.On save below condition is checked and displays flash message.I need to add ember selector to this flash message.When i add attr using jquery it doesn't display selector on flash message inspect element.

On controller save click i call this function

```
    if(productDontAllow && (!!userManagement))
    {
      this.get('emberGrowlService').showNotification({
        message: messageDisplay,
        type: success
      });
      Ember.$('.ember-growl-notification-item').attr('data-test-flash-failure','')
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [growl docs](https://github.com/jerel/ember-cli-growl/blob/master/README.md), you can define a custom template at `app/templates/components/growl-instance.hbs`. You could add the test selector there.

My guess is that your code doesn’t work right now because the DOM element hasn’t been created yet when the JQuery selector runs. You could test this by using a setTimeout to delay the JQuery code, however I don’t recommend keeping that in the codebase.

Alternately, if this is something your app depends on a lot, you could suggest it as a feature in the addon itself, and if maintainers approve, make a PR. That seems like a useful thing to be able to do.